# How to get the total Gitlab CI/CD minutes used from the API?

Tags: gitlab

I'm looking to get the total number of Gitlab CI/CD minutes used for a group using the API. It would be useful to also get the group's quota/minutes left.

I saw [this documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/cicd_minutes.html#view-cicd-minutes-used-by-a-group) on how to get it from the website, but it doesn't specify how to get it from the API.

I also saw the "Can I proactively monitor my CI/CD Minutes usage?" section on [this page](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/faq-consumption-cicd/#managing-your-cicd-minutes-usage), but the projects it links to seem to all of the pipelines and then aggregating their durations. I'd prefer it if I could make a single API call to get the total minutes used.

Comment: A couple of us were discussing GitLab CI/CD in the [Git chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55870620#55870620) just now. Perhaps we can chat there if you're interested!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure out now by looking at the API calls from the website on the `https://gitlab.com/groups/<my group>/-/usage_quotas` page.

It uses a query like this with the [Gitlab GraphQL API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/getting_started.html):

```
{
    ciMinutesUsage(namespaceId: "gid://gitlab/Group/<group ID>") {
    nodes {
      month
      monthIso8601
      minutes
      projects {
        nodes {
          minutes
          project {
            id
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "ciMinutesUsage": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "month": "January",
          "monthIso8601": "2023-01-01",
          "minutes": 3,
          "projects": {
            "nodes": [
              {
                "minutes": 3,
                "project": {
                  "id": "gid://gitlab/Project/<project ID>",
                  "name": "Description"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you only want to get the usage for the last month, you can change your query to `ciMinutesUsage(namespaceId: \"gid://gitlab/Group/<group ID>\", first: 1)`.